# How to access the value of this json token to store in in local storage

Tags: json, angular

```
 loginUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user)
    .subscribe((success: any) => {
      if(success) {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', success.token);
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(success.token));
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

What is returned https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1MG7.png
Result in storage https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofsms.png

I want to store the value of the token

Changing this to

```
localStorage.setItem('access_token', success);
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(success));
```

Result - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWYuW.png

Comment: I have explained the issue. You can check and see if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set success.success.token instead.

Better to rename the response as `response`

```
loginUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      if(response) {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.success.token);
        // localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.success.token)); probably not needed.
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unnecessary wrapping over the response object. Remove that or use response.success.token to get to the token string.

your code becomes:

```
loginUser(user: any) {
    return this.http.post(this.loginUrl, user)
    .subscribe((response: any) => {
      if(response) {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.success.token);
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```